# Dynamic CRM 2011 delete quote products and push new quote products

Tags: c#, dynamic, crm, quote

I am working on the Dynamic CRM SDK to push the quote' products from an external application. Following code is working fine to push the product to the CRM. The products are pulled from SQL database from an external application and push to dynamic crm.

```
DataSet DS = GetAllCRM_Details(oppid);
DataTable table = DS.Tables[0];

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{

string prodid = DbCommon.ToStr(row["txtcrmprodid"]);
double Qty = DbCommon.ToDouble(row["intquantity"]);
string Note = DbCommon.ToStr(row["txtproduct_note_internal"]);
string ProdDesc = DbCommon.ToStr(row["txtproductdiscription"]);
string qid = DbCommon.ToStr(row["txtcrmquoteid"]);
string UnitCrmID = DbCommon.ToStr(row["UnitID"]);
string price = DbCommon.ToStr(row["floatlistprice"]);
string lineid = DbCommon.ToStr(row["intQlinID"]);
string price_fltTotal = DbCommon.ToStr(row["floattotal"]);
string quotedetailid = DbCommon.ToStr(row["txtcrmquotedetailid"]);
string productname_qt = DbCommon.ToStr(row["txtproductname_qt"]);


decimal nprice = 0;
decimal ManualDiscountPrice = 0;
decimal pricefltotal = 0;


if (price != "")
{
    nprice = Convert.ToDecimal(price);
}

if (price_fltTotal != "")
{
    pricefltotal = Convert.ToDecimal(price_fltTotal);
}


ManualDiscountPrice = (nprice - pricefltotal) ;



decimal extamount = nprice * Convert.ToDecimal(Qty);


// Set the quote's product quantity to a negative value.

QuoteDetail quoteDetail = new QuoteDetail()
{

    ProductId = new EntityReference(Product.EntityLogicalName, new Guid(prodid)),                            
    IsProductOverridden = true,
    ProductDescription = productname_qt,
    IsPriceOverridden = true,
    Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(Qty),
    PricePerUnit = new Money(nprice),
    CTDescription = ProdDesc,
    CTInternalNote = Note,
    ManualDiscountAmount = new Money(ManualDiscountPrice),              
    QuoteId = new EntityReference(Quote.EntityLogicalName, new Guid(qid)),
    UoMId = new EntityReference(UoM.EntityLogicalName, new Guid(UnitCrmID))
};

_quoteDetailId = _serviceProxy.Create(quoteDetail);
```

The first attempt is working fine,When user make an amendment and try to push the products to crm the existing products in the CRM need to updated/delete the exiting product and add the new products.
The product quote details id(guid) are stored in the external tool database.
Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track for creating a product.

For updating please follow below steps,

1. Using the information from your source, retrieve the information from CRM to get the GUID for the record to update. for that you can use _serviceProxy.Retrieve() or _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple() methods.
2. Once the record is available, create an entity for the product and assign the id of this entity to the record which we retrieved in the first step and use _serviceProxy.Update(). This will update your existing product.

Now if you want to delete and create a new record follow below steps,

1. Retrieve the record as in the case for Update.
2. using _serviceProxy.Delete() method delete that particular record from the CRM
3. Follow your existing code to create a new product with updated info.

Its recommended to update the record rather than always deleting and creating a new record.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

We would like to delete all the product details for the quote and add the new product will speed up the process. I could not get to work with above code.

Code example will be really helpful.